# cURL work in console but not work in browser

Tags: php, ssl, curl

```
  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'hello_world');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd().'/ca.pem');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/client.pem');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd().'/key.pem');

  $post = array(
    // ...
  );

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, join('&', $post));

  $curl_result = curl_exec($curl);
  $error = curl_error($curl);

  var_dump($curl_result);
  var_dump($error);

  curl_close($curl);
```

this script work in console "php simple.php"
but this script not working in browser

boolean false

string 'NSS: private key not found for certificate: PEM Token #1:client.pem' (length=67)

please help

```
`
    cd /path/to/simple.php; ls -la
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 ujin apache 1.4K Jan 19 19:03 simple.php
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ujin apache 2.6K Jan 19 15:58 ca.pem
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ujin apache 1.6K Jan 19 15:59 client.pem
    -rw-r--r-- 1 ujin apache 1.1K Jan 19 16:18 key.pem
`
```

Comment: fixed! disabled proxy and restart httpd. thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can't find the ca.pem and friends. Some things to try

- Put in the absolute paths
- make sure, access rights are OK for the webserver process

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php tells us, that CURLOPT_CAINFO needs an absolute path!

EDIT (after discussion with @UJin):

please try the absolute paths:

```
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'hello_world');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $cwd=getcwd();

  //DEBUG
  echo "cwd=$cwd\n";

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "$cwd/ca.pem");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "$cwd/client.pem");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "$cwd/key.pem");
```

Comment: Please elaborate: WHat did you change (update your OQ) and has the error thrown changed?

Comment: Please post the output of "cd /path/to/simple.php ; ls -lah"

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx 1 ujin apache   1.4K Jan 19 18:51 simple.php

Comment: This is proof, that the paths to ca.pem and friends is wrong: Inside simple.php, if you do "curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'ca.pem');", ca.pem must be in the same directory as simple.php, which it is not. So where are your ca.pem and friends?

Comment: Please, UJin be a bit more cooperative: WHAT did you change?

Comment: UJin: This is the last time I ask that: WHAT IS THE OUTPUT? I have put in a line saying echo "cwd=$cwd\n"; - give me that output.